# Translate Lead/Lag function to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I translated the below codes so that it runs in MySQL. I am new to MySQL and finding it difficult to understand few things.

CODE 1:

```
SELECT t1.user_id,
           t1.visit_month LEAD (t1.visit_month, 1) OVER (partition BY t1.user_id ORDER BY t1.user_id, t1.visit_month)
    FROM (SELECT 
    user_id,
    month(date_time) as visit_month
FROM
    tbl_activity
    group by 1, 2
ORDER BY 1 , 2) t1;
```

Desired Output for Code 1

[image]

CODE 2:

```
SELECT user_id,
       visit_month,
       lead,
       lead — visit_month AS time_diff
FROM table3
```

CODE 3:

```
SELECT user_id,
       Visit_month,
       lag(visit_month, 1) over (partition BY user_id ORDER BY user_id, visit_month)
 FROM table
```

CODE 4:

```
SELECT user_id,
       visit_month,
       lag,
       visit_month — lag AS time_diff
 FROM table2
```

Comment: You can take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could express the `lead()` and `lag()` function via `subquery`

```
select user_id, month(date_time) as visit_month,
       month(date_time)-(select month(date_time) from tbl_activity 
                         where user_id = a.user_id and 
                         month(date_time) < month(a.date_time)
                         order by month(date_time) desc LIMIT 1) as time_diff -- This could be re-express via lag() function
from tbl_activity a
group by user_id, month(date_time);
```

In above you would need to just specify `<` / `>` to express the `lead()` and `lag()` functionality in subquery and don't forget to use `order by` clause

**EDIT (Lead) :**

```
select user_id, month(date_time) as visit_month,
       (select month(date_time) from tbl_activity 
       where user_id = a.user_id and 
       month(date_time) > month(a.date_time)
       order by month(date_time) LIMIT 1) as lead -- This could be re-express via lead() function
from tbl_activity a
group by user_id, month(date_time);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh for the reply. However, I am still struggling with the select top in MySQL. Would be great if you could provide the exact query.

Comment: Everything looks good Yogesh. I am getting error for a.month in the subquery which says FUNCTION a.month doesnt exist. I tried to give other alias names but stil the same. Any thought?

Comment: I guess its month(a.date_time)

Comment: @user9651591... I see there was some typo and i have corrected it.

Comment: the code ran perfectly but it did not give desired output. I have placed an image of my expected outcome in the question

Comment: @user9651591... Ohhh this is `lead()` not `lag()` !!

Comment: Very helpful - exactly what I was looking for. Also, I think you mean `a.user_id` instead of `t.user_id` in both versions of the query

Comment: @Anupam. .  Yes. it is referring same `a`.